# I want to create an image in reStructuredText, which will have an alternative (<alt>) in html and still work in pdf

Tags: restructuredtext

So I'm writing reStructuredText which creates an HTML page and a PDF at the same time. I'd like to add alternative text for the image in HTML, but when I add it in my code the image doesn't work in the PDF!

My code without alternative text (which work in both case):

```
.. image:: https://********.jpg
```

My code that doesn't work in PDF:

```
|alternative en plusieurs mots|

.. |alternative en plusieurs mots| image:: https://*********.jpg
```

Comment: The non-working alternative defines an inline-image without "alt" text. This will work in PDF generated by rst2latex and latex but may be unsupported by the 3rd party "rst2pdf" tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation of the docutils [`image` directive](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#image), the following should work:

```
.. image:: https://********.jpg
    :alt: alternative en plusieurs mots
```

Comment: Thanks ! It work perfectly I feel stupid ahaha